# Cannot find an overload for KeywordQuery in Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, search

I am trying to run the following line:

```
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery($ctx)
```

and receive this error:

> New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "KeywordQuery" and the
>   argument count: "1".

**1.** I have added paths to SDK:

    `Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
    Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 
    Add-Type -Path "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search\v4.0_16.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.dll" 
    Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.dll"`

Full code:

```
  $ctx=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
  $ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $AdminPassword)
  $ctx.Load($ctx.Web)
  $ctx.Load($ctx.Site)
  $errorMessage=""
  try
  {
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
  }
  catch [Net.WebException]
  {
    $errorMessage=$_.Exception.ToString()
  }

Write-Host $ctx.Web.Url
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery($ctx)
```

**2.** The library is correct and sample code works in C# in Visual Studio:

```
static ClientContext ctx;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Credentials();

            ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, ss);
            DoSomethingSearchish();
        }

        static void DoSomethingSearchish()
        {
            KeywordQuery kQ = new KeywordQuery(ctx);
            kQ.QueryText = "prank";
            SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(ctx);
            ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(kQ);

            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (var resultRow in results.Value[0].ResultRows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(resultRow["Title"]);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

*The Visual Studio code was originally copied from somewhere, altered and used by me, but I cannot find the source now - apologies to the author.*

**3.** In Powershell, using different number of arguments for the constructor gives the following errors:

0 - ...Query.KeywordQuery

> A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor
>   for type Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery

2 - ...Query.KeywordQuery($ctx, "")

> New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "KeywordQuery" and the
>   argument count: "2".

**4.** I am NOT running the code from SharePoint Online Management Shell (it is installed though) and I am NOT connected with Connect-SPOService.

**Question: Why Powershell cannot find the constructor?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works now. What helped:

1. Close ISE.
2. Close all Powershell windows (regardless whether they are connect to SPOService or not).
3. Restart.

I think partial explanation for this is available in this post:
[Error creating PeopleManager object using CSOM in powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135140/error-creating-peoplemanager-object-using-csom-in-powershell)

Restarting Powershell must have helped unload the wrong reference and load the correct assembly and appropriate constructor.